# How to extract the keyword from a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher

Tags: encryption, cryptography, caesar-cipher, cryptanalysis

I am a beginner to cryptography and i have the following the question. I know that to extract a plaintext from a mono-alphabetic  substitution cipher i can perform shifting the characters by n times until i have the plaintext, or i can also use the frequency letter analysis. However by doing this im getting only the plaintext and not they keyword thats been used.
The answer might include creating a table with the alphabet linked to the corresponding letters used in ciphertext by following the frequency letter analysis but im not sure how this works. Can someone explain to me how i will be able to get the keyword?

Comment: This question is best asked on https://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you access the plaintext than use the equations to get the key!

Comment: You may be confusing a Caesar cipher: shift n letters with n in [1..26] with a keyed monoalphabetic cipher, where the alphabet is rearranged using a keyword: Key: ALPHABET -> ALPHBETCDFGIJKMNOQRSUVWXYZ.  Not all monoalphabetic ciphers have a keyword, [Atbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash) for example.